# Copper braid as heatsink

Tags: heatsink

Somebody recently asked me about this headlight: https://www.hsd-il.com/products/h7-72w-8000lm-led-car-headlight-bulbs-cree-led-chips-6500k-drl-copper-belt-headlights-12v-24v
[image: LED headlight]

Interesting. I'm not sure copper braid is going to work very well to get rid of the heat dissipated by those LEDs. The known reputable manufacturers don't appear to be using this method.

Has copper braid has worked well as a heat sink in your designs?
Can you provide links to examples?
If this was useful, why haven't I seen it before?

Edit: Let me clarify.
My questions are not about LED headlights. I'm trying to find out if any of you designers have used this copper braid method of heatsinking your power devices. (Or seen it done in something other than LED headlights).

Comment: I guess that's a cheap way to get lots of surface area for minimal copper but you pay for that with conduction through a small cross section compared to a block heatsink. I know that applying a 250C soldering iron to one end of a 2" strip will quickly exceed 60C at the far end because you burn your fingers.

Comment: `Would others please chime in` ... this site is not a forum ... poll type questions are off topic ... please ask a specific, answerable question

Comment: https://thermal-space.com/thermal-straps/   https://www.techapps.com/copper-thermal-strap-assemblies

Comment: Edited post to ask specific, answerable questions.

Comment: @Antonio51, the second link you gave (https://www.techapps.com/copper-thermal-strap-assemblies) specifically (per thermal conductivity vs temperature chart) refers to properties at cryogenic temperatures (0 to 120K). I'm still looking for use of copper braid at higher temperatures (25C to 150C).

Comment: The lamp manufacturer may be constrained by shape of space behind headlights of many different car models, so chose flex braid as an alternative that can be bent to shape. Perhaps a small fan might give more confidence.

Comment: Never tried something like that but copper is a great thermal conductor (the best that is not exotic).

Comment: Ok. It was only for "examples" ...

Comment: Tinned copper wire has acted as a very efficient heatsink when I have mistaken it for solder

Answer (score 1):

Well, first thing to say that the heatsink is made of copper. Although it's tin-plated, it still has higher (almost twice) thermal conductivity compared to aluminium. So, that's a +1 point.

The construction brings very high surface area. So, that's another +1 point.

[image]

<sub>Image Source: Amazon</sub>

Copper's density is higher than aluminium's. So, for a heatsink with the same size, copper will be much heavier. But this construction doesn't look like that heavy. Maybe as heavy as an aluminium block heatsink. So, that's the final +1 point.

I googled it expecting to see some applications but the only application I could found was headlights. And it's getting popular, from what I understand. [Here](https://blog.betterautomotivelighting.com/how-hot-do-led-headlight-bulbs-get) is a link showing some experiments and results.

Final thing I'd say is that this design looks like relying on the airflow inside the car chassis for the best cooling performance.

Answer (score 0):

[Fan vs. aluminum vs. copper heatsink, which one has the best cooling?](https://bestaftermarketledheadlight.jimdofree.com/page1/)

> we examined all the various heat sinks on the various LED bulbs. This
> **flexible style was among the least hot** out of all of them. We began with the original halogen light bulb ordinary temperature about
> 150 degrees... After that we put in among the flexible knotted style, ran it for 30 minutes as well [and] got an ordinary temperature of 143 [degrees] on the backside...
>
> The nonfan, aluminum, non-flexible style were
> around 15 to 20 percent hotter than the initial halogen bulb. And
> **the flexible heat sink style was 15 to 20 percent cooler than the initial housing light bulb.**

Comment: Does a link and a copy/paste from that link constitute an answer - I thought there was a rule against that?  Your link should be a comment - not an "answer".  The link isn't very informative and test method details are not given.